# Finding Value exist in Range List

Tags: linq

I have a list of weekranges of Year Quarters.

Example:

1. WeekStart =1, WeekEnd= 13
2. WeekStart =14, WeekEnd= 26
3. WeekStart = 27, Weekend = 40

If i pass a input weeknuber as 20, Which is in the range of 2nd record, Return true.
If i pass a input weeknumber as 45, return false as it doesn't exist in any records.

How can i do this in LINQ Query.

Please help.

Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this is what you are looking for.

```
        public class WeekRange
        {
            public int Start { get; set; }
            public int End { get; set; }
        }

                var data = new List<WeekRange> 
                { 
                    new WeekRange{Start = 1, End = 13},
                    new WeekRange{Start = 14, End = 26},
                    new WeekRange{Start = 27, End = 40}
                };

       var existing = data.Where(w => w.Start <= 20 && w.End >= 20).FirstOrDefault();

      var nonExisting = data.Where(w => w.Start <= 45 && w.End >= 45).FirstOrDefault();
```